# I'm trying to make a rainbow tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def RainbowButton():
    btn.config(bg=red)
    btn.config(bg=purple)
    btn.config(bg=yellow)
    btn.config(bg=orange)
    btn.config(bg=blue)
    btn.config(bg=lightblue)
    btn.config(bg=green)
    btn.config(bg=black)
def ButtonUpdate():
    RainbowButton()
    window.after(10, ButtonUpdate)
ButtonUpdate()
```

This is the code I came up with, but it's not working. The button is just black when I run the program, no colors are changing.

Comment: Widget state changes only get processed when you return to the mainloop - so your colors other than black never have a chance to actually be applied to the Button, not even for a millisecond.  You would need to apply a single color at a time, and wait until the next time your function is invoked via `.after()` to apply the next color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to feed the colors to the button one at a time, once for each time the `ButtonUpdate()` function runs. You can solve this by using an iterator. When the iterator runs out of items it raises an error which I capture with the `try` clause. I adjusted the time for the `after()` function so the effect can be seen better.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(window, text='Button')
btn.pack(padx=50, pady=30)

rainbow_colors = ['red','purple','yellow','orange','blue',
                  'lightblue','green','black']
color_iterator = iter(rainbow_colors)

def ButtonUpdate():
    try:
        color = next(color_iterator)
        btn.config(bg=color)
    except StopIteration:
        return
    window.after(500, ButtonUpdate)

ButtonUpdate()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle


window = tk.Tk()

class RainbowButtonApp:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.window = window
        self.setup_ui()
        self.start_color_cycle()
    def setup_ui(self):
        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.window, text='Click me!')
        self.button1.pack(padx=50, pady=30)
    def start_color_cycle(self):
        self.rainbow_colors = cycle ( ['red', 'purple', 'yellow','orange', 'blue','lightblue', 'green', 'black'] )
        self.change_color ()
    def change_color(self):
        color = next ( self.rainbow_colors )
        self.button1.config ( bg=color )
        self.window.after ( 500, self.change_color )
    def change_color(self):
        color = next ( self.rainbow_colors )
        self.button1.config ( bg=color )
        self.window.after ( 500, self.change_color )

app = RainbowButtonApp(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).